# Write faster loop function in javascript due execution time out

Tags: javascript, loops, runtime-error

My friend John likes to go to the cinema. He can choose between system A and system B.

**System A** : buy a ticket (15 dollars) every time

**System B** : buy a card (500 dollars) and every time 
    buy a ticket the price of which is 0.90 times the price he paid for the previous one.

## Example: If John goes to the cinema 3 times:

```
    System A : 15 * 3 = 45
    System B : 500 + 15 * 0.90 + (15 * 0.90) * 0.90 + (15 * 0.90 * 0.90) * 0.90 
    ( = 536.5849999999999, no rounding for each ticket)
```

John wants to know how many times he must go to the cinema so that the final result of System B, when rounded up to the next dollar, will be cheaper than System A.

The function movie has 3 parameters: card (price of the card), ticket (normal price of a ticket), perc (fraction of what he paid for the previous ticket) and returns the first n such that

```
ceil(price of System B) < price of System A.
```

**More examples:**

```
movie(500, 15, 0.9) should return 43 
    (with card the total price is 634, with tickets 645)
movie(100, 10, 0.95) should return 24 
    (with card the total price is 235, with tickets 240)
```

I wrote this code but i get a timeout message on the webpage. Can someone suggest me how can i write a faster code than this?

```
   function movie(card, ticket, perc) {
var WithTicketPrice = 0;
var WithCardPrice = card+ticket*perc;
var Counter = 1;

while (WithTicketPrice <= Math.ceil(WithCardPrice)) {

      WithTicketPrice = WithTicketPrice + ticket;

      WithCardPrice = WithCardPrice + (ticket*Math.pow(perc, Counter)*perc);
      Counter++;

    }

  return Counter-1;

};
```

Comment: please add some use cases (function call) with the wanted result as well.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the answer you are looking for (exiting `i`) can be phrased with a single mathematical equation, in which case you won't need a loop at all.

Comment: No matter how fast you loop, the exit condition is simply going to be unreachable.

Comment: Amusingly, this is a bit like Heracles and the turtle. Only in this case Heracles will never reach the turtle not because of some philosophical mumbo jumbo but because he's heading in a different direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exit criteria will probably never happen as of the code you quoted, because you increase the `WithCardPrice` by `ticket` squared. This way the `WithTicketPrice` won't just start lower but will be always smaller all the time, given `ticket > 1.0` and `card > 1.0`.

I guess you wanted to write

```
WithCardPrice = WithCardPrice + ticket * (1 + i * perc);
```

or something like that?